# knife node list VS knife exec -E 'nodes.all.each {|n| puts "#{n.name}"}'

Tags: chef-infra, devops, knife, infrastructure

I'm trying to understand why the output of

```
knife node list
```

vs

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.all.each {|n| puts "#{n.name}"}'
```

Don't give me the same node names. I would expect the above commands to show me the same names but at the moment there are discrepancies, seems like any new node isn't picked up in the second command (`knife exec..`)

Any idea what might cause this and how to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for `knife node list`, it looks like this command will not output all of the nodes if you have an environment listed in your knife.rb file. It looks like running `knife node exec` returns the raw node object.

See the code here for `knife node list`: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/f53ad6511b7fcc40576f05688dc17b11ad58e089/knife/lib/chef/knife/node_list.rb#L37-L40

See code here for the `nodes` object: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/f53ad6511b7fcc40576f05688dc17b11ad58e089/lib/chef/shell/ext.rb#L461-L463